# Confusion with window.load function

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between using the functions:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
        //do something
  });
```

and

```
  $(window).on('load', (function() {
        //do something
  });
```

Basically I have a page which loads a number of images (sometimes around 100). I prefer not showing the page until all the images have loaded. What I see is, if I use the second function, sometimes the function is never executed. Cannot understand why this is happening

Comment: So what I understand is that the first function is basically doing nothing and hence seems to be working fine. While actually that might not be the case

Answer (score 1):

The [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event:

> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "load", handler )`.

Comment: So that means both the functions will have the same behaviour

Comment: Exactly what you said. :)

Comment: Note that this was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 3.0.

Comment: [jQuery 3.0 Release](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) says: use `.on()` to register listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), as mentioned before, it's deprecated and removed from jquery lib.

use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
What it does (.on('load',function())) is simply wait until all the associated elements (binded with the url, including images) are loaded, and then content of the handler is executed.

If you're using ajax to load your images, it may not work everytime, because the **window** element may be concidered fully loaded during the xhr request.

If so, use [.ajaxStop()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) instead.

for exemple:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('img').show();
});
```